# why httpbackend not working in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, jasmine, angular-ui-router

I am trying to test $http webservice using $httpBackend ? I am getting a error in that . how to test service using $httpbackend ?

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/S3LFymv8hrxtatWaCv1A?p=preview

```
it('call http service', function() {

  authRequestHandler = httpBackend.when('GET', 'data.json')
    .respond([{
      "name": "hello"
    }, {
      "name": "hello12"
    }, {
      "name": "hello22"
    }, {
      "name": "hello45"
    }]);

  httpBackend.flush();
  service.callData().then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
    expect(response.data.length).toBe(4)
  })
})
```

Comment: You haven't told it to expect that GET request. You need to tell it to expect one

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
authRequestHandler = httpBackend.when('GET', 'data.json')
  .respond([{
    "name": "hello"
  }, {
    "name": "hello12"
  }, {
    "name": "hello22"
  }, {
    "name": "hello45"
  }]);

service.callData().then(function(response) {
  console.log(response)
  expect(response.data.length).toBe(4)
})

httpBackend.flush();
```